# Why CSS declaration do not apply?

Tags: css

I need to make another skin from an ancient css file. So, I added #header custom declaration after original one.

```
#header {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#0000FF;
line-height:30px;border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}

;; many lines passed

#header {
    background-color: #999 !important; 
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

There is html
http://mazas.pro/111/page.php

If you look in browser's console #header element (blue one) you'll see original blue declaraion:

[image]

and even not a mention of second declaration in right column, but if you click dark.css file link and scroll down the line 1542 - you'll see another declaration with another background color, which do not apply here. Ramarkably that the same additional #page rule, placed near-by do work. I'm quit bewildered.. What's going on here?!

Comment: _“Ramarkably that the same additional #page rule, placed near-by do work. I'm quit bewildered.. What's going on here?!”_ — why not debug this further? Delete all CSS code. Other than these two declarations. Does it still work? Delete only half the CSS code. Does it still work? Etc. Please include a [mre] in the question. I’m not going to click on a random link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Semiconols on line 1541 and 1550 of your dark.css are destroying your css file.

Remove the ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; theme settings ;;;;;;;;;;;;;
and ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;